# Back up deja dup produced lots of duplicity.gpg files

Tags: backup, deja-dup

I made a back up using the ubuntu default application for back ups and it created a folder called deja dup where inside it had lots of duplicity.gpg files

Was this the intended result? I thought it would make one big tar file..
If this was the intended result, then the deja dup folder itself is the folder I would need to restore, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deja Dup uses duplicity for backups and that splits them in multiple files. To restore data you need the whole directory. There is no single archive.